# Disable formatter in JSP Eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

How can I disable the eclipse formatter for JSP temporally, I know in java is somehing like:

```
// @formatter:off 
// @formatter:on
```

But

```
<!-- @formatter:off -->
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates, as you know.
```

There is the list of templates, defaults given by Eclipse
At the bottom of the dialog, in Eclipse Juno (4.2), I see a checkbox Use code formatter. Unchecking it deactivates the auto-format at insertion time.

Comment: I don't want to to disable it completely, I want to disable from line 100 to line 130 for example.

Comment: you must check you formatter  on/off enabled or not follow this Windows → Preferences → Java → Code Style → Formatter

Press the "Edit" button. Choose the last tab, the On/Off, and enable them with a checkbox.